# Compress Raster Overviews

Tags: gdal, compression, gdaladdo

I have a large number of Raster Aerial images which I have been building VRT files for.  I'm also building overview for them with the following code

```
gdaladdo -r average -ro Y:/vrt/sussex_2016_aerial.vrt 2 4 8 16 32 64
```

The orginal images are GEOTiffs and I would like to create compressed overviews but I'm struggling to understand the code required, which I need to add to the above line.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4):

Gdaladdo manual page http://www.gdal.org/gdaladdo.html contains an example that creates small jpeg compressed overviews which suit well for aerial images.

> Create an external JPEG-compressed GeoTIFF overview file from a 3-band
>   RGB dataset (if the dataset is a writable GeoTIFF, you also need to
>   add the -ro option to force the generation of external overview):
>
> gdaladdo --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW JPEG --config PHOTOMETRIC_OVERVIEW
>   YCBCR
>            --config INTERLEAVE_OVERVIEW PIXEL rgb_dataset.ext 2 4 8 16